# Implementing $(this) in a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, long-click

I've been looking for developing a long-click plugin to handle such an event in jQuery, and after much research, I've found the best method. I've created the plugin below. It is not a large file, but it covers what I need. There are some problems with it though...

```
$(function($) {
  var holdTimer;
  $.fn.longclick = function( handler, time ) {
    if(time == undefined) time = 500;
    return this.mouseup(function(){
      clearTimeout(holdTimer);
    }).mousedown(function(){
      holdTimer = window.setTimeout(handler, time);
    });
  };
  $.fn.longclick.defaultTime = 500;
}(jQuery));
```

Below, I have the page that tests it:

```
// some markup
<input type="button" name="button3" id="button3" value="1500ms">

// and... the script itself

$("#button3").longclick( function() {
  var initial_text = $("#button3").val();
  console.log( $(this) );
  var initial_id = $(this).attr("id"); console.log( initial_id);
  var initial_html = $(this).html(); console.log(initial_html);
  $("#button3").replaceWith('<input type="textbox" id="" value=' + initial_text + '>');
}, 1500);
```

Now, the problem of my plugin seems to be that it doesn't know what `$(this)` means. When I `console.log` the `$(this)` it return the window itself, not the button that I need... Also, `initial_id` and `initial_html` are *`undefined`*. **How can I get this done?**

**UPDATE:** The `initial_html` variable should be, in my case `<input type="button" name="button3" id="button3" value="1500ms">`. The `jQuery.html()` won't work as I expect by saying `$(this).html()`. **How can I get the element's HTML?**

Comment: change console log to alert.
i.e. alert(initial_id) and alert(initial_html)

Comment: how will this change anything?

Comment: this will show you a exact value in alert box.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your approach has a serious issue.  What if I `mousedown` on a button then move my mouse off of that button and `mouseup`?  Will this not fire a long-click when it shouldn't?

Comment: you can come up with a better approach if you know one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `setTimeout(handler, time)` the `handler` will be called from `window` (`this` will be equal with `window`).

So, when you init the plugin instance you have to save `this` into a `$self` (it's a jQuery object). Then instead of `setTimeout(handler, time)` you have to do:

```
holdTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
    handler.call($self);
}, time);
```

The edited plugin is:

```
$(function($) {
  var holdTimer;
  $.fn.longclick = function( handler, time ) {
    var $self = this;
    if(time == undefined) time = 500;
    return this.mouseup(function(){
      clearTimeout(holdTimer);
    }).mousedown(function(){
        holdTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            handler.call($self);
        }, time);
    });
  };
  $.fn.longclick.defaultTime = 500;
}(jQuery));
```

Regarding the HTML of the old element, `jQuery.html()` takes the inner HTML. You need the `outerHTML`. So, you get it this way: `$(this)[0].outerHTML`.

```
var initial_html = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
console.log(initial_html); // <input type="button" name="button3" id="button3" value="1500ms">
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yKnGr/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Inside `setTimeout` the value of `this` is always the window, and you you're calling the callback from the scope of the setTimeout function.

```
$(function ($) {
    var holdTimer;
    $.fn.longclick = function (handler, time) {
        return this.on({
            mouseup : function () {
                clearTimeout(holdTimer);
            },
            mousedown : function () { 
                var self  = this;
                holdTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
                    handler.call(self);
                }, time || $.fn.longclick.defaultTime);
            }
        });
    };
    $.fn.longclick.defaultTime = 500;
}(jQuery));
```

You have to get the element the event handler is working on, otherwise the callback will apply to all elements, see this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yKnGr/2/) for an example on how that would **not** work.

Comment: It's not the same, this sets `this` in the callback to the element clicked, yours set `this` in the callback to the entire collection, and yours was just a codedump until you updated it, and I was a little slow testing in a fiddle to make sure this was the issue, and writing a proper answer.

Comment: @adeneo What's the use case of setting the `self` in the callback of `mousedown`?

Comment: @IonicãBizãu - Uhm, affecting only the current element, and not all of them would be the use case I suppose ?